# making files under folder accessable by their url

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlet-filters, web.xml

I have a  webproject in J2ee , now there are some files which can be access directly by typing thier URL and some files which cannot be  accessed
EG  files under folder admin/xyz.js are Not accesble
but files under folder common/xyz.js is accessable

now i want to remove this and make all files accessable due to some resons(pls note this).
From where do i need to remove secuity rectriction?

Comment: there can be many configuration that can restrict this, what security framework is used in your app ?

Answer (score 0):

See in your WEB-INF/web.xml --> <security-constraint> section.